# How to select a radio button by clicking its container

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, label

I am developing a web-application using Rails 4.2 and bootstrap. 
In a form where the user selects a video from their playlist, I attempt to output the users' videos in the following format:

```
<div class="form-group select_video">

   <h3>Select Playlist Video</h3>

   <table class="table">    

   <% @user.playlist_videos.each do |playlist_video| %>

      <label for="playlist_video_<%= playlist_video.id %>">

          <tr class="study_video_instance">
              <td><%= radio_button_tag "playlist_video", "#{playlist_video.id}" %></td>
              <td><%= Topic.find(Video.find(playlist_video.video_id).topic_id).name %></td>
              <td><%= full_name_of(Speaker.find(Video.find(playlist_video.video_id).speaker_id)) %></td>
          </tr>

      </label>

    <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want the user to be able to select a video by clicking on the `<tr>` tag wrapped inside the `<label>` tag.

However, my browser renders the following:

```
<div class="form-group select_video">
<h3>Select Playlist Video</h3>

    <label for="playlist_video_18"></label>
    <label for="playlist_video_24"></label>
    <label for="playlist_video_25"></label>
    <label for="playlist_video_26"></label>

<table class="table">...</table>
</div>
```

**PROBLEM**

All my labels are collapsing and appearing ABOVE the table when rendered in the browser.

Please help me understand what I am missing.

Comment: You can't put a `<tr>` inside a `<label`>. You're breaking the basic table structure with that (`<label>` can't be a direct descendant of `<table>`) and your browser just tries to mitigate this error. For the rest of your task, I'd just try to catch the `click` event with JavaScript and go on from there.

Comment: What @maryisdead says is the correct answer. But in case you're wondering, yes, you can have multiple labels for the same input element, so it's no problem to have to repeat the same label in the three table cells.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I will try solving my problem with JavaScript.